# stop loss triggers with the position

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v4

I often have a problem with my stop loss. It starts immediately after placing a position. I have tried various ways to fix it but unfortunately it failed. Does anyone know where the problem is? Thank you!

```
longLossPerc = input(title="Long Stop Loss (%)", type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, 
defval=1) * 0.01
shortLossPerc = input(title="Short Stop Loss (%)", type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, 
defval=1) * 0.01

longStopPrice  = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - longLossPerc)
shortStopPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + shortLossPerc)

strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, when=long, comment='Long',alert_message = 
message_long_entry)
strategy.exit( "SL","Long", stop=longStopPrice, comment = "SL Long",alert_message = 
message_long_exit)
strategy.entry('Short', strategy.short, when=short, comment='Short',alert_message = 
message_short_entry)
strategy.exit( "SL","Short", stop=shortStopPrice, comment = "SL Short",alert_message = 
message_short_exit)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57XFi.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the id of the exit order should be unique:

```
strategy.exit("SLL","Long", stop=longStopPrice, comment = "SL Long",alert_message=message_long_exit)
strategy.exit("SLS","Short", stop=shortStopPrice, comment = "SL Short",alert_message=message_short_exit)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this error still occurs after the change. I will just add that most often it occurs after large movements